# JBPM 7.31 how to expose a REST service to close task

Tags: rest, service, task, customization, jbpm

in JBPM is possible to expose a custom REST Service in order to close custom task?

in the example below the process must wait a REST call from an external application in order to close the process.

How I can implement this requirement in JBPM 7.31?

[image: Process example]

Answer (score 1):

If you remove `manager.completeWorkItem(workItem.getId(), results);` from [RESTWorkItemHandler](https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/blob/main/jbpm-workitems/jbpm-workitems-rest/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/rest/RESTWorkItemHandler.java#L863) process execution will wait for completion of REST task. You can manually complete this task through kie-server REST API

```
[PUT] /server/containers/{containerId}/processes/instances/{processInstanceId}/workitems/{workItemId}/completed
```

Inplace of making REST task wait I will suggest to add Intermediate timer node or Intermediate Signal node inplace of REST task.

Answer (score 1):

having a signal or receive task would make more sense here instead of creating Url for each process instance to complete. you can provide your implementation of the receive task i.e. a generic service that completes your task. or a signal that you can trigger when your custom rest service is invoked.